# vk api, php, sdk

Tags: php, api, вконтакте, sdk

Есть код

```
echo 'ABC\n';
$vk = new VKApiClient();
echo '123\n';
```

Первое echo выводится, второе нет, почему? Ошибок нет, библиотека подключена, обьект $vk рпботоспособен.

Comment: `var_dump ($vk)`, чтобы люди видели, что он рабочий и содержит что-то вменяемое. Второй момент - где указанная версия ? В документации не сказано, что её можно не указывать (`$vk = new VKApiClient('5.101');`). Ну и третий момент - зачем использовать этот шлак ? Гуглите за simplevk, или напишите себе свою либу.

Comment: var_dump ($vk) не срабатывает после второй строчки, версию указал, ничего не изменилось. За simplevk спасибо, но пока бы с этим разобраться :)

Comment: Если скачивать официальный VK API SDK на PHP, то там необязательно указывать версию. Достаточно будет просто создать новый экземпляр класса VKApiClient без указания каких-либо параметров

Comment: Оказалось, что VKApiClient.php не видит VKApiRequest.php. Косяк библиотеки, или я их как то по-особенному должен подключить? Править файл VKApiClient.php и инклудить там VKApiRequest не вариант. Как грамотно подключить? У себя в коде инклуд не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Если первый echo выводится, а второй нет, значит всё-таки где-то есть ошибка. Возможно, у вас отключен вывод ошибок. Попробуйте в начале файла прописать `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. Если и это не помогло, попробуйте найти ошибки в файле `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (для *unix)

Comment: Оказалось, что VKApiClient.php не видит VKApiRequest.php. Косяк библиотеки, или я их как то по-особенному должен подключить? Править файл VKApiClient.php и инклудить там VKApiRequest не вариант. Как грамотно подключить? У себя в коде инклуд не помогает.

Comment: подключаю так `include_once('путь к папке/VK/Client/VKApiClient.php');`
`use VK\Client\VKApiClient;`

Comment: я просто сделал автоинклуд. Во время запуска приложения инклудятся абсолютно все .php файлы.